# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de puntuar? "¿Pero y eso...?", "Pero ¿y eso...?" o "Pero, ¿y eso...?"

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación

¿Cómo sería la puntuación correcta de esta pregunta?

1. ¿Pero y eso cómo se come?
2. Pero ¿y eso cómo se come?
3. Pero, ¿y eso cómo se come?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bangs/inverted exclamation marks (¡) and queries/inverted question marks (¿) within a sentence](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/bangs-inverted-exclamation-marks-and-queries-inverted-question-marks-wit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De los tres casos, la opción segunda (2) sería la correcta

> **Pero ¿y eso cómo se come?**

El primer ejemplo es incorrecto en relación a la posición del signo de pregunta, de acuerdo a lo que prescribe la RAE [sobre el empleo de los signos de interrogación](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n),

> d) Los signos de apertura (¿ ¡) se han de colocar justo donde empieza la pregunta o la exclamación, aunque no se corresponda con el inicio del enunciado; en ese caso, la interrogación o la exclamación se inician con minúscula (→ mayúsculas, 3.4.2b):
>
> Por lo demás, ¿qué aspecto tenía tu hermano?

La tercera versión tampoco es correcta, por cuanto:

> 3.3. No se escribe coma detrás de pero cuando precede a una oración interrogativa o exclamativa: Pero ¿dónde vas a estas horas?; Pero ¡qué barbaridad!

(según las [reglas del uso de la coma](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma))